# Recursion paths from coordinate to coordinate

Tags: java, recursion, path, point

I'm working on a **java** assignment for a class and I'm unsure how to solve this problem. I don't want it completed for me, but get me started in the right direction. I'm mostly unsure of the recursive part of the program. I'm not very good at programming.

> problem:
>
> > NorthEast paths are obtained from a
> >     two-dimensional grid by moving up and
> >     right. For example, in the figure
> >     below, there are two paths from 1,0 to
> >     0,1. The first is (1,0), (0,0), (0,1),
> >     the second is (1,0), (1,1), (0,1).
> >     Note that there are no NorthEast paths
> >     from (0,1) to any other point. Also
> >     note that there is one NorthEast path
> >     from (1,1) to (0,1). You are to write
> >     a program that takes a number (size of
> >     grid - no larger than 10) and a
> >     starting location and an ending
> >     location and recursively computes all
> >     of the "NorthEast" paths.

0,0 0,1

1,0 1,1

I'm reading in the file prog2.dat

which reads in the grid size first and then the starting coordinates and then finishing coordinates. for example:

5

3 0

1 3

It needs to be one files, so I'm going to use methods. If someone could get me started or direct me to a similar question already posted, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean NorthWest?  From (1,0) to (0,0) and (1,1) to (0,1) are moving to the *West* not East.  Or have I misunderstood the definition?

Comment: You can only move up and right, hope that clears up things. Trying to figure all the paths from 1,0 to 0,1. Although I'm working with a 5x5 grid in the actually program, the 1,0 0,1 is an example.

Comment: His grid defines (0,0) to be in the upper left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution involving recursion involves finding the next point on the path that will get you closest to your destination.  Once you have that point, you then use the same method to figure out the next closest point and so on.  This process (or the recursion) ends when you have arrived at your destination.

You can try doing something like this:

```
void getNextPoint(Point start, Point end, Path currentPath) {
    //if start == end, then you're done with the recursion
    //and you have a valid path

    //if you can move east from start to get closer to end
    //Point next = east of start
    //append next to the currentPath
    //then call getNextPoint(next, end, currentPath)

    //if you can move north from start to get closer to end
    //Point next = north of start
    //append next to currentPath
    //then call getNextPoint(next, end, currentPath)
}
```

I've omitted a lot of details so you can figure out more for yourself, but that's one approach to using recursion.  Essentially, you're building up a path.  You'll have to figure out how to manage your Paths, but chances are you will need to be able to push and pop points off of them.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading about [Pascal's Triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle).

For a given starting location (x0, y0), and a given ending location (x1, y1), and restricting yourself to moving North or East on a grid, a minimum-length path will consist of precisely (x1-x0) steps to the East and (y1-y0) steps to the North, in some order.